# Get object from comparison of one of its parameters

Tags: java

I'm working on a library project; there is a Library class:

```
public Library(int id, String libName, String libAddress, double libBudget, boolean libEnabled)
```

And a Librarian class:

```
Public Librarian(int id, String firstname,String surname,
    String email, String nss, String password, int role, int library, boolean enabledLibrarian)
```

Each Librarian is assigned to a Library:

```
Librarian.getLibrary(int x);
```

The project scope requires the management of several libraries, so I have a controller that generates my list of Libraries at the beginning

```
 public static List<Library> libraries()
```

The methods for purchasing a book, approving a loan, etc. are all under the class Library(). What I am not sure how to do is to get the instance of the object Library() where the parameter of Library() is equal to that of the corresponding parameter in Librarian() -

```
     private static void LibrarianLanding(Librarian librarian, Library library) {
    System.out.println("Welcome, " + librarian.getFirstname() + " " + librarian.getSurname());
    System.out.println("You are in the Admin area of Library No." + librarian.getLibrary());

    Library library = libraries.get() //WHERE library.getID() == Librarian.getLibrary();
    library.PurchaseSomeBooks(librarian);
```

Probably its something very simple I am missing.

Answer (score 0):

If you change your List of Libraries to a Map of Libraries keyed by the Library id like this:

```
Map<Long, Library> libraries;
```

Then you can retrieve by key like this:

```
Library library = libraries.get(librarian.getLibrary().getId())
```

However, if librarian.getLibrary() returns you the Library for that Librarian anyway, why do you need to get it from a List (or Map)? Maybe librarian.getLibraryId() makes more sense?